# Step by step implementation procedure for Promoted Builds Plugin (Manual approval)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to implement code promotion from `DEV environment to QA environment` for that i use a Git repository to put tag list name.

If user will update new tag list into the git repository then Jenkins will automatically trigger the particular job.

so, my requirement is whenever tag list get update with new tag list names one notification mail should go to the approver Email id and that mail 
should contain Job URL so that approver can go to that URL and approve the job.

To implement this requirement I am using `"Promoted Builds Plugin"`. I tried a lot but can't be able to implement. Can any one give a step by step
procedure for same requirement.

Comment: What have you implemented already and where are you struggling? It's a bit hard to explain everything

Comment: I created git repository where tag list file will save and one Jenkins job which will do a check in into the QA environment. I want to configure the job in between them.  Workflow should be like this.           Git repository ---> job approve process ----> if job approved by Authenticated person ----> tag will get promote to QA environment.

Answer (score 0):

Install all suggested plugins and Promoted Builds[Simple] and promoted builds plugin.

1. Setup Job A
2. Configure Job A to send email to your "approver" as part of Email Ext post-build action.
   Use the “Promote Builds when” feature to add approval as part of the job configuration & trigger a notification to approvers upon successful build of A.
   Add an Action to trigger Build ‘B’ as part of the post approval step.
   Add a ‘Post Build Action’ to trigger email upon success of ‘A’ to approvers.
3. Configure the email to contain link back to the job run.
   In the Default content section add this: ${BUILD_URL}promotion
4. Configure a Promotion on Job A
5. In that promotion, allow it to be run only by your "approver" user (by name)
6. Configure that promotion to trigger Job B
7. Upon successful execution of Job A, this email will be triggered to approvers which can be approved.